# How to store multiple hour ranges in a day for multiple businesses in a database

Tags: mysql, datetime

I've found a lot of questions on this topic but a lot of them don't seem to address multiple hour sets in a day. Currently I have a closing time and opening time variable for each day of the week. My issue is for businesses that say are open from 8am - 2pm and 5pm - 11pm, or something of the sort. The closest thing I have come up with is a string variable for each day of the week formatted as such: "08:00-14:00;17:00-23:00" and then just split by semicolons and then dashes and I would have my sets. However I have read that you do not want to store times as a string, in general. What would be the issue with this? or is there a better way to store and process multiple time frames in a day.

EDIT:

I have a table representing a given market area, each entry into this table is a different restaurant containing various information about them: GPS coords, address, phone number, opening/closing times, etc. Currently I have 14 timestamp columns for opening and closing times; one opening and one closing for each day of the week. I have already written an algorithm to determine if a place is open or not that works great, even when a place closes after midnight, and just needs to be passed the opening and closing times. I am looking for a solution to potentially store multiple time sets in a day.

Comment: why you do not use some fields with TIMESTAMP data type. you can query them fast.

Comment: Best way makes the question opinion based. Think about a 1:n table (timeframes) with (day, start [(date)time],end [(date)time])

Comment: @Gholamali-Irani timestamp is what I'm currently using. But my issue is what about if a business closes in the middle of the day. My current setup with a opening time and closing time column does not support this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers here are close to my needs but I had do combine them with something else I found on Google. Where I went wrong was not considering multiple tables. I assumed, as this was data pertaining to the businesses that are in my original table, that the hours should be in this same table. My end result is a separate table for hours containing columns for business id, day of the week, opening time, and closing time. Then when pulling hours, I pull all rows that contain the business id and day of the week needed. This supports as many time frames as needed in a day and allows me to pull data in a manner that will still work with my current algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct to think that you shouldn't be storing time as strings in your database; you should be storing them as a **[`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)** (which also covers time). Ideally, what you'd be doing is having one column for `start time` and another column for `closing time`. Each date would have both.

Then you would calculate the difference between the two **server-side**.

Considering you're working with a large number of **days**, I'd actually recommend making use of a secondary table (called `Hours` in my example). Have your days map out to set 'ranges' in the `Days` table, and have those hours correlate to specific times in the `Hours` table.

In the following example, the `Hours` field in `Days` correlates to the Primary Key `ID` of `Hours`:

#### Days

```
ID |    Name   | Hours
----------------------
1  |   Monday  |   1
2  |  Tuesday  |   2
3  | Wednesday |   2
```

#### Hours

```
ID |    Start   |     End   
---------------------------
1  |   08:00:00 |  18:00:00
2  |   10:00:00 |  20:00:00
```

---

## EDIT

If you open and close multiple times per day, you'd need to switch the tables, and make the `Hours` table show which days contain those hours:

#### Hours

```
ID |    Start   |     End   |   Day 
-------------------------------------
1  |   08:00:00 |  10:00:00 |    1 
2  |   12:00:00 |  14:00:00 |    1 
3  |   10:00:00 |  20:00:00 |    2
```

#### Days

```
ID |    Name   
---------------
1  |   Monday
2  |  Tuesday
3  | Wednesday
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: What you initially described is my current setup but neither of your examples cover if a business closes down in the middle of the day. I need to be able to have an indefinite number of opening and closing times.

Comment: I only provided one example; the two tables would be joined together. Assuming you only open once per day and close once per day, you'd simply need to add more columns to the `Hours` table, and then assign the `Days` table to the relevant foreign key `ID`. If you open and close multiple times per day, you'd need to **switch** the tables, and make the `Hours` table show which days contain those hours. I've updated my answer to cover this as well :)

Comment: Is this example for one business or multiples? This seems only practical if I'm storing data about 1 business, unless there's something I'm not seeing?

Comment: That would be an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378); Your original question said  "*for a business*". Not multiple businesses. Use a bridging table if you're dealing with multiple businesses, joining on whatever is common between them.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, work has kept me busy. I apologize, I had misspoken in the title but had said 'businesses' in the body of the question. However your answer did get me in the right direction. I guess I just hadn't thought of using multiple tables, seemed unorganized to me at first, but I am new to databases. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create a separate relation for hour sets. I cannot provide you with the exact code, but the overall idea is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE day_of_a_week (
    day_name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL;

    CONSTRAINT PK_day_of_a_week_day_name PRIMARY KEY (day_name);
);

CREATE TABLE time_period (
    day_of_a_week_name TEXT;

    start_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
    end_time   TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;

    CONSTRAINT FK_day_of_a_week_time_period FOREIGN KEY (day_of_a_week_name)
        REFERENCES day_of_a_week (day_name)
        MATCH FULL
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

A neat feature of the proposed solution is that you may use the same `time_period` relation to define special working hours for some particular dates.

This way you may define multiple time periods for each day. However, this solution has one significant drawback - data duplication. The same time period may be defined for multiple days.

This issue may be resolved with a many-to-many link between `day_of_a_week` and `time_period`. But I am not sure about whether it is a good solution for this particular problem.